# Loading popover content with ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an ajax call to display a show method content for different products  in popovers in my page.

I use the following code:

```
function details_in_popup(link, div_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function(response){
            $('#'+div_id).html(response);
        }
    });
    return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
}

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    "html": true,
    "title": '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>'+
            '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" >&times; </button>',
    "content": function(){
        var div_id =  "tmp-id-" + $.now();
        return details_in_popup($(this).data('url'), div_id);
    }


  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function(e){
  var popover = jQuery(this);
  $('body').on('click','.close', function(e){
    popover.popover('hide');
  });
 });
});
```

The problem that i am encountering is that the first time i open a popover, the content get filled properly, the second time, i get title duplicates in the popover, then the third time, content from the first popover and the second one get all mixed up.

It's like if the previous popovers are never cleaned-up and get accumulated each time i open a new popover...

Is there something obvious in the code that might be creating this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you opening the popup?

Answer (score 0):

reset the div on `ajax success` with

```
$('#'+div_id).text('');
```

than append the response.

Comment: I was gonna suggest `$('#'+div_id).empty().html(response)`, they can try both.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But it didn't solve my problem yet... I tried both approaches and it didn't make a difference in my behaviour...